# Dreamweaver Minify Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, dreamweaver, minify

Is anybody aware of a plugin that can be used with Dreamweaver or any other coding utility that can minify your javascript/css as you upload the files?

So for instance, I create a file called `functions-global.js`, and then, when I upload the file, it uploads this file as it is and creates a minified duplicate called something like `functions-global.minified.js`?

I cannot imagine it would be a very hard plugin to write, as long as you have the minifying algorithm which is used here for js - [Compress Javascript](http://jscompress.com/), and this one for CSS - [Compress CSS](http://www.minifycss.com/css-compressor/)

I use dreamweaver purely for familiarity purposes, if there is any other software out there that does this then please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a dreamweaver extension for minifying js:

http://www.dwbooster.com/miscellaneous/javascript-minify

Comment: This is similar to what I want, but it is not quite right. Firstly, the algorithm used is not very good. It does not minify variable names! I would also like it to do it automatically when I upload the files, I do not want it telling me that it has done it. Thanks anyway

Comment: I'm afraid, you've then need to write your own custom script.... The built in libraries that are available, you've already mentioned them in your question.

Comment: Okay, will proceed to doing this. :-)

Comment: 7 years later... so have you done it? If you managed to make your own custom script could you make it publicly available, let's say put it on GitHub, and share the link here? @BenCarey

Comment: @s3c There so many tools available online these days that never felt like creating one of my own.

Comment: @AlphaMale thats to bad.. In our company most of us use VS Code or Sublime Text 3, but one senior is sticking to DreamWeaver... Aince I don't find a simple minifier extension, he is stuck at saving style.css, then I have to update my local style.css and save it so the style.min.css is updated and uploaded as well...

Comment: @s3c - I ended up writing my own PHP framework that handled all of the necessary minification, as well as many other things. After a year or two, I found another framework that was doing exactly the same, but was doing it even better with the support of the open source community; introducing Laravel. After familiarising with Laravel, I migrated to Lumen, where I further adapted the framework to my own bespoke implementation, and that is now what I use on _most_ PHP based projects... However, for static JS projects, I do not use Lumen, I use webpack instead... (part 1/2)

Comment: @s3c When I first started out as an engineer (almost 20 years ago), as much as I hate to admit it, I did use Dreamweaver, simply because it was what I had at the time. It took me a while (okay, a long while...), but migrating to a proper IDE (PHPStorm in my case) was one of the best moves I ever made. I mean the following statement with love; if your 'senior' engineer is still using Dreamweaver in 2020, and is not familiar with JS module bundlers such as webpack, then I would politely suggest that he is not so senior :-)

Comment: @BenCarey I appreciated your input. Upvoted. We are (now seriously) discussing moving to Laravel, and will hopefully manage that in the next few months. Now off to google-ing Lumen :)

Comment: @s3c - I wouldn't advise looking into Lumen until you have familiarised yourself with Laravel. Lumen is an optimised and trimmed down version of Laravel, specifically engineered for stateless API development, and optimised for speed around this. Whilst you can technically use Lumen to build frontend websites, it requires having a thorough and deep understanding of the Laravel framework components.

Comment: @BenCarey Noted. Thanks again! PS: It's nice to see someone who had many questions 7 years ago, actually explaining answers in depth after passed time.

Comment: @s3c - I learned everything I know from asking questions, picking the brains of those who know more than me, and reading other's code. Learning from others is the fundamental key to getting better. Moreover, asking questions about things you don't understand, instead of just copying and pasting them into your project, is also essential. Including library after library in your projects just because they 'do the job' is one of the keys to becoming a **terrible** engineer, something that has littered the coding industry.